# Materialize dropdown behind scrollbar

Tags: html, css, material-design, materialize

So the problem is as the title states... I have a small drop-down that when shown, hides itself under the scrollbar...

[image: image of the problem]

**CSS for the dropdown:**

```
.dropdown-content {
@extend .z-depth-1;
  background-color: $dropdown-bg-color;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-height: 650px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  will-change: width, height;
}
```

Also here is the .**js code from Materialize framework** in case anyone thinks that there is something that can be done in the .js:

```
      // Position dropdown
  activates.css({
    position: 'absolute',
    top: origin.position().top + verticalOffset + scrollOffset,
    left: leftPosition
  });
```

I have tried changin the `overflow` in the css but nothing happens...

So doeas anyone have any idea how to resolve this issue or is there a way to overlay the scrollbar??

**NOTE: Im using Materialize framework and Meteor**

**EDIT** Is is possible to write a function in **javasacript** that would calculate the position of the click event and display the dropdown where the click event happened?